# What do these base Spline function actually mean?

Tags: interpolation, spline

So I was trying to understand what these spline functions actually mean, but I am stuck. What I came up with was that between 2 specific nodes xi-1 and xi+1, depending on where x is, the spline functions give us a fraction of an interval.

Thank you for your help. I want to understand how the linear spline interpolation works, but this is different from what I found on the internet, where I didn't find this specific form.

Thank you

[image: spline base functions]

[image: spline interpolation]

Comment: This is a linear interpolation. Normally, the word "spline" is used for 3rd degree polynomials (as in cubic spline) but in general it can be defined for any degree, like here for 1st degree.

Comment: These basis functions are called "tent functions" (think to the shape of a tent): taking any linear combination of them, you get all functions that are continuous and affine by intervals on each interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$. As said by PC1, these functions can be called degree 1 splines, not the most usual (the most usual ones are degree 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the b-spline basis functions of degree 1. Each of them is a “hat” or “tent” shape. The $i$-th function $S_i$ has the value 1 at $x_i$, and then it’s value descends linearly to zero on either side (at $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i+1}$).

By taking linear combinations of these basis functions, you can get any piecewise linear function. In fact, the piecewise linear function that has the value $y_i$ at $x=x_i$ is just
$$
S(x) = \sum y_iS_i(x)
$$
B-spline basis functions are often defined recursively, via the deBoor-Cox algorithm: the degree 2 one’s are defined in terms of the degree 1 one’s, the degree 3 ones are defined using the degree 2 ones, and so on. Look up b-spline basis functions, or look [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-basis.html) or [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-ex-1.html).